# How to calculate time between rows with condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table in SQL Server about how people going in and out of building.

| user_id | datetime | direction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27.09.2022 10:30 | in |
| 1 | 27.09.2022 12:30 | out |
| 1 | 27.09.2022 14:30 | in |
| 1 | 27.09.2022 15:35 | out |
| 2 | 27.09.2022 11:30 | in |
| 2 | 27.09.2022 13:20 | out |
| 2 | 27.09.2022 15:00 | in |
| 2 | 27.09.2022 15:40 | out |
| 3 | 27.09.2022 11:45 | in |
| 3 | 27.09.2022 11:46 | in |
| 3 | 27.09.2022 15:40 | out |
| 3 | 27.09.2022 15:47 | in |
| 3 | 27.09.2022 18:00 | out |

I need to calculate how much time each user spent inside the building by days.
For example, on 27th Sep user #1 spent 3 hours 5 minutes. User #2 spent 2 hours 30 minutes.
There is also a bug that may spoil the results - sometimes I may have two 'in' or two 'out' in a row, like in case of user #3. I understand the nature of such bug, and know I only have to keep last of two same rows (in fact user #3 entered in 11:46, not 11:45).  Does anyone have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: Given this pattern: `In Monday 10pm Out Tuesday 1am In Tuesday 2am Out Tuesday 5am....` Would you report Monday as 2 hours and Tuesday as 4 hours?

Comment: If the first record of the day is out, that means he/she/x was IN the building, so theoretically, that should count, too.
Analog, if there is no out record, does that mean, that the employee was NOT IN? In essence: you need to cover your edge cases, before a solution can be built

Comment: Your sample data should include the shoulder events

Comment: Also, I show user 1 has 03:05:00 not 03:30:00

Answer (score 1):

The window functions would be a nice fit here.

**Example or [Updated dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7UxCjqS1)**

```
Select user_id
      ,Duration = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(Secs),0))
 From (
        Select user_id
               ,Secs = datediff(second,case when direction ='in' 
                                             and lead([direction],1) over (partition by user_id order by datetime)='out' 
                                       then [datetime] 
                                       end
                                       ,lead([datetime],1) over (partition by user_id order by datetime))
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Group By user_id
```

**Results**

```
user_id     Duration
1           03:05:00   -- << Check your desired results
2           02:30:00
3           06:07:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select    user_id
         ,sum(time_spent) as time_spent_minutes
from     (
         select *
                ,datediff(minute, lag(case when direction = 'in' then datetime end) over(partition by user_id order by datetime), datetime) as time_spent
         from t 
         ) t
group by user_id
```

| user_id | time_spent_minutes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 185 |
| 2 | 150 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VPmK5GpQ)